# Grab SQL being executed in a shell script

Tags: sql, unix, shell, sybase

Given a shell script containing a bunch of SQL statements, is there an option to redirect just the SQL statements to stdout/file?

The structure of the script is something like this:

...

```
for i in *list*  
do  
  isql *credentials etc* <<EOF > a.out  
  select *about 100 cols*  
from $i + "_TAB"  
go  
EOF  
done
```

...

Query has been simplified, and is quite complex in reality.

How can I grab the actual statements that are executed when I run this script?

Much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The -e (and often with -n) option will echo the input [Sybase document for isql](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility210.htm) although you will get the output as well. If you want to not have the output - selects etc you will need to write a function called isql that will echo the command line to one file and run the isql to another
 (easier in perl or python)

Comment: Apologies for the delayed reply. Yes, this option would work, but was hoping that I didn't have to code much :)

Anyways thanks, Mark!

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to hold your here doc, then you can echo it.

```
for i in *list*  
do  
    read -r -d '' select <<-EOF
        select *about 100 cols*  
        from $i + "_TAB"  
        go  
        EOF  
    isql *credentials etc* <<< "$select"
    echo "$select" > a.out
done
```

The hyphen after the `<<` allows you to indent the here doc, but only with actual tabs. Tabs converted to spaces, as is done automatically by some editors, will not work.

Comment: Dennis, apologies to you too for the delayed reply.

I tried this, but didn't work at all. First, the 
<code>echo $select</code> 
gave me a funny output (listing of all files in pwd), and then there were no records returned from the DB (it should; query is correct).

Comment: I'm sorry, the `$select` should have quotes around it since your query probably has asterisks in it. I've edited my answer.